# getting exception as org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP

Tags: java, exception

Getting error as below

> An error occurred at line: 14 in the jsp file:
>   /MLIncludeRunTimeJS_CSS.jsp The type JSInfo is ambiguous

```
11:     String lCSSFile = "";
12:
13:
14:     JSInfo lJSInfo = (JSInfo)session.getAttribute(SessionConstants.JS_INFO);
15:
16:     if(lJSInfo != null)
17:     {
```

Please suggest a solution.

After Adding fully qualified name getting below error

An error occurred at line: 16 in the generated java file
Only a type can be imported. com.orbitech.frameworks.mline.utils.JSInfo resolves to a package

Stacktrace:
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:439)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:334)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:312)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:299)
        at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:586)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:317)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.processActionForward(ActionServlet.java:1759)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1596)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:492)

Comment: do you import it?

Comment: `ambiguous` is mean you import more than one class definition of `JSInfo`, try to use full classification, e.g. `com.somepackage.JSInfo`

Comment: ok thanks , will try this

Comment: Actually i am not getting this error on unix but getting it on tomcat.